# While switch the store i want the configuration filed should be Blank

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, multistore, system.xml

While switch the store i want the configuration filed should be Blank.
 By default means One store information should not contain in another store . Right now i need to edit the information manually . What i need text filed should be bank . Is there is way to achieve this Programatically

[image]

Answer (score 1):

By design the lower scopes "inherit" values from higher scopes (not literally, but inferentially).

Having these default to be truly empty would require custom dev and would break a ton of stuff. It's not a wise idea.

Comment: Thanks Ben But can we have any idea about this how to achieve through Custom development

Comment: You need an event observer. How you implement it will be up to you - again, I cannot imagine a good reason for this approach, and it will have far-reaching impacts.